# definition of Black swan random variables

Tags: definition, risk, heavy-tailed

What's the precise mathematical definition of a black swan random variable?

Taleb describes it approximately here(http://highlands.vmhost.psu.edu/_reading/docs/blackswan.pdf), where he describes three properties:

1. large impact
2. incomputable probabilities
3. surprise effect

It appears that this might simply be a heavy-tailed distribution whose parameter is a function of what is known and unknown about the dynamics of the system in question(ex. global economy). Now, my guess is that this function is difficult to evaluate because:

1. What is known about the system has a shaky underlying theory.
2. What is unknown about the system is underestimated.

However, I think that the fraction of Black Swan random variables in a system can be reduced over time assuming that information about the system's behaviour grows over time. I think biological evolution is one example of this.

In fact, I think that 'Black Swans' would fit in well within Leslie Variant's theory of Probably Approximately Correct Learning(http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos511/scribe_notes/0214.pdf)

These are some rough ideas as it appears that very little work on a technical definition has been done. But, I might not have searched enough. I look forward to hearing what others have to say.

Note 1: I think Black swan events and Black swan random variables can be defined in terms of each other. Black swan events are the elements of the sigma-algebra generated by the Black swan random variable.

Note 2: I actually asked Taleb for a mathematical definition via Twitter. But, he ignored this request.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this, and my feeling is there is no precise definition. However, wouldn't a "black swan" be an **event** rather than a *variable*? (e.g. variable = "swan color")

Comment: There is a lot of discussion about Taleb and his book The Black Swan on this CV site.  I even started a question that got a lot of attention here. His book was very negative toward statistics even though he was a little kinder .in the second edition.  Black Swans are rare events.  So a Black Swan random variable should be nonnegative with a heavy right tail.  Taleb claimed they were unpredictable event.  I am guessing because I have never heard of a Black Swan random variable.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I think that they can be defined in terms of each other. Black swan events are the elements of the sigma-algebra generated by the Black swan random variable.

Comment: It could be that the "black swan" events are supposed to be "well separated" from the "typical" events? So perhaps considering the distribution as a mixture? e.g. "0-inflated swan albedo PDF" :)

Comment: So I would argue that you cannot define this.  Taleb really does all of this in a very informal manner.  There are many variables, such as stock market variables, where this happens normally.  One of my favorite stocks, for demonstration purposes, had a 70,000,000% return.  It also collapsed.  It went from 5 cents per share to 35,000 dollars per share to 4 cents per share over a two year period.  Strangely, if you read the news it all makes a sort of sense.  It was still "irrational" from a discounting of cash flows perspective, but you could see how it happened.  Wishy-washy phrases are bad.

Comment: @user25459 I agree. So essentially "black swan" = "unknown unknown" (The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns) even links the two, under "see also"!)

Comment: I think the "unknown unknown" part is absolutely essential. He talks about how there are no black swans in gambling at casinos, because everything is well-defined mathematically and the risks the casinos face are incorporated into their work. But the building of the casino burning down is a black swan, because it's an event with major consequences which you assume won't happen and don't think about.

Comment: "Incomputable probabilities" make this a non-mathematical concept and "surprise effect" strongly suggests it's a *psychological* concept.  *A fortiori* there can be no mathematical definition, nor would an attempt at one be useful.